# Get ExtJS component by class

Tags: extjs3

I want to retrieve ExtJS component by using *class name* that is I want the same result when I tried to retrieve element by using *id*. I can do it by using *id* but there are some issues occurs when I provide id to my components.
Below is one item which present on one page and I want to get it on another page (internally pages are connected) by using class name.

```
  {
    ref: 'reasonCodeField',
    cls: 'reason-code-field',
    xtype: 'enumcombo',
    enumName: 'SCH.TrackingEventReasonCodes',
    allowBlank: false
  }
```

**Now how can I get component by using class name?**

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Why do you need to find a component by its css class? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call `Ext.getCmp` with the ID from the DOM element:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.reason-code-field');
const component = Ext.getCmp(element.id);
```

Two big caveats:

1. I'm not sure if this will always work. It works for me in a simple example.
2. There is probably a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to accomplish (see my comment asking for more details).